# How to run app in older version of Simulator

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, ios6, ios5

I would like to know how it is possible to run an iPhone app in previous versions of the iPhone simulator.

I have Mountain Lion, and the lateset xcode 4.5 and latest monotouch and monodevelop.

I have tried to download older xcode and iOS 5.1 sdk, but not sure how to get monodevelop to run the app inside of the older simulator.

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MonoDevelop will use the version of Xcode that you provide in the **SDK locations** preferences (of MD). By default it will use `/Application/Xcode`

From this version of Xcode, e.g. 4.5, you can download additional iOS simulators. To do so you go to the **Xcode** menu, **Preferences**, select the **Downloads** tab, select **Components** and click on the **Install** button (e.g. for iOS 5.1 Simulator).

The restart MonoDevelop and it should pick up the extra simulator targets.

To see/change them go to the (MD) **Project** menu and select **iPhone Simulator Target**. You should see a list (starting with **Default**) of all iOS versions available (with one item for **iPhone** and one for **iPad**).

Select the one you want and the run (or debug) your application...

Comment: Glad it helped. Please take the time to mark the question as answered (checkmark under the votes) so other people searching for this can quickly find it.

Comment: For me it doesn't show older versions than iOS 10.3.1. However, I need to test for iOS 9.0. How would I access this version?